# Получение токена Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-api, facebook-graph-api, facebooksdk

Такой вопрос: есть ли способ получения токена ФБ для работы со страницами, формами и лидами без использования браузера. Дело в том , что мне нужно слать запросы скриптом на php и вытаскивать лиды, но для того чтобы вытащить лиды, нужно сперва вытащить id форм по каждой страницы, но при тестировании обнаружил, что общий токен не подходит, а нужен именно свой токен для каждой страницы. Можно ли както это обойти?

Comment: curl-запросы из php-скрипта пробовали?

Comment: Да пробовал. Не проканывает